# Need to add several running totals columns in one code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I created one column for a running total from one column source but I need more than one running totals from different columns sources. How do I do that in one code?

```
;WITH RunTot AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER()over(partition BY memberid
                                    ORDER BY OriginalSubmitDate,OriginalSubmitTime) AS ROW,
                   MemberID,
                   Convert(varchar(12),OriginalSubmitDate,101) AS 'OriginalSubmitDate',
                   Convert(varchar,OriginalSubmitTime,108) AS 'OriginalSubmitTime',
                   TotalDrugCostonClaim
   FROM dbo.Holly_QICRestack_Modified
   WHERE ClaimStatus <> 'X'
     AND MemberID = '01317453701')
SELECT ROW,
       MemberID,
       OriginalSubmitDate,
       OriginalSubmitTime,
       TotalDrugCostOnClaim,

  (SELECT Sum(TotalDrugCostOnClaim)
   FROM RunTot b
   WHERE b.memberid = a.memberID
     AND b.row <= a.row) AS RunTotal
FROM RunTot a
```

Comment: Just repeat the last subquery changing the column

Comment: I tried and I am missing something - would appreciate if you can show me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
;WITH RunTot AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER()over(partition BY memberid
                                    ORDER BY OriginalSubmitDate,OriginalSubmitTime) AS ROW,
                   MemberID,
                   Convert(varchar(12),OriginalSubmitDate,101) AS 'OriginalSubmitDate',
                   Convert(varchar,OriginalSubmitTime,108) AS 'OriginalSubmitTime',
                   TotalDrugCostonClaim
   FROM dbo.Holly_QICRestack_Modified
   WHERE ClaimStatus <> 'X'
     AND MemberID = '01317453701')
SELECT ROW,
       MemberID,
       OriginalSubmitDate,
       OriginalSubmitTime,
       TotalDrugCostOnClaim,   
  (SELECT Sum(TotalDrugCostOnClaim)
   FROM RunTot b
   WHERE b.memberid = a.memberID
     AND b.row <= a.row) AS RunTotal,
 (SELECT Sum(SomeOtherColumn)
   FROM RunTot b
   WHERE b.memberid = a.memberID
     AND b.row <= a.row) AS OtherRunTotal
FROM RunTot a
```

Comment: Tried and nope :(

Comment: I just fixed it....had to move a couple things around....I want to check yours off but can't as it was sloppy....